# I'm trying to make a program which you choose an angle

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to make a program which you choose an angle, and it tells you it's respective Sin, Cos and Tan. But, I can't figure out why all of the angles I use have the same answer (Sin 0, Cos 1 and Tan 0. Can someone help me out?

```
#include <math.h> 
double angulo;
double seno;
double cosseno;
double tangente;
double rad;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

 Serial.println("Programa para calcular sen, cos e tg");
 delay(1000);
 Serial.println("Digite o angulo");
 angulo = Serial.parseInt();
 rad = angulo*0,0174533;
 seno = sin(rad);
 Serial.println("Seno");
 Serial.println(seno);
 cosseno = cos(rad);
 Serial.println("Cosseno");
 Serial.println(cosseno);
 tangente = tan(rad);
 Serial.println("Tangente");
 Serial.println(tangente);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written

```
rad = angulo*0,0174533;
```

But, C++ uses the american decimal notation:

```
rad = angulo*0.0174533;
```

Thus, you have been multiplying `angulo` by zero every time.

Comment: I guess this is a language thing, where some cultures use a comma as a decimal indicator, and a full-stop as a thousands separator... I.e., they are backwards.

Comment: Saying it is backwards implies there is a correct (forward) and wrong (backwards) way, but of course they are merely different ways of denoting the same concept.

Comment: My way is right and every one else's is wrong ;) "Right" is whatever the majority of people use....

Comment: Doesn't the C++ comma operator calculate and discard the first expression and then use the following expression for the assignment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work